# Viotek monitor clips in and out when running above 144Hz

Tags: display, desktop-computer, intel-core-i5

I just built my first PC; I’m fairly new to building computers. I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 card and an Intel i5 12600K processor. I just bought a new Viotek (GNV32DBE) monitor for my PC. It is capable of 165Hz and it’s 2560x1440p. I am also running Windows 11.

My problem is when I change my refresh rate settings to 144Hz or 165Hz, my monitor clips in and out between my display and a black screen. 119.99Hz seems to work fine. 119.99Hz doesn’t look bad, but I’d really like to get max performance. Are my listed components not able to support 144Hz or 165Hz? Or is there something more I need to do in my BIOS? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It mainly happens when I move my mouse around.

EDIT (2/6/23): I discovered answer to the issue after speaking with my coworker. The issue would happen when I would move my mouse around while watching Hulu. My coworker suggested that it may be because Hulu runs at a different refresh rate. With my monitor being set to 165Hz while watching Hulu, it may have set it off because of the mismatch in refresh rates. Nonetheless, I set my monitor to 165Hz yesterday and played a game and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Since the PC shows the refresh rate, the Graphics hardware supports it. I looked up the monitor, it's supposed to support it. How is your mouse connected?  Try updating its driver.  Try the monitor on another PC

Comment: It’s a wireless perixx mouse. Do you mean update the drivers on the mouse? I was able to get it up to 144Hz while playing a game, was scared to go to 165Hz though